# What is the meaning of && in PostGIS?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

In PostGIS, what is the result of the `&&` operation between two geometries? In my mind, `&&` returns a `boolean`, but does return `geometry` this time. In the following example, the operation is between a `LineString` and a `Polygon`.

Firstly, I guess this is the relationship between inclusion and being included. Until I do the following example, I think this should be a relationship of type "intersection". Am I right?

```sql
select ST_geomfromtext('linestring(0.1 0.1,1.9 1.9)', 4326) && st_geomfromtext('POLYGON((0 0,0 1,1 1,1 0,0 0))', 4326)
```

The result is `t` which represents `true`.

Comment: Note that `&&` is also the "overlaps" operator for [arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) and [ranges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html) and the `AND` operator for [full text search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-textsearch.html)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's an intersection operator [`&&`](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_overlaps.html)

> `boolean &&( geometry A , geometry B );`
>
> `boolean &&( geography A , geography B );`
>
> The `&&` operator returns `TRUE` if the 2D bounding box of geometry `A` intersects the 2D bounding box of geometry `B`.

How one could find it using google:

1. Search for "postgis operators"
2. On the first page https://postgis.net/docs/reference.html search for `&&`

Comment: Think you very much ,It's just what I need.

Comment: They should have had human-readable operator there, like INTERSECTS_WITH, rather then going with &&.

Comment: @jayarjo it's a domain specific knowledge: from set theory it's known that sets intersection (or conjunction) is a `∧` or `&`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. And still - it's SQL we are dealing with, they should have followed usual conventions.

Comment: @jayarjo `ST_Intersects` ?

Comment: Is it an equivalent? Awesome.

Comment: ST_Intersects is a PostGIS Function - I'm not sure if it can perform intersects on non-geometric / geographic types or arrays, whereas I was able to use && to assess the overlap of date ranges, for example

Answer (score 0):

diff between `&&` and `st_intersect`.
https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html

> If a geometry or geography shares any portion of space then they
> intersect. For geography -- tolerance is 0.00001 meters (so any points
> that are close are considered to intersect)

So it's **possible** that `boolean &&( geometry A , geometry B );` return true, but `st_intersects(geometry A, geometry B)` return false. example: https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/indexing.html

But `boolean st_intersects(geometry A, geometry B)` will yield the **same** result as `boolean &&( geometry A , geometry B );`